# random array android from string

Tags: android, arrays, random, text

I want to assign the numbers of my array at random to the keys key0, key1 etc ..

I'm using this code where in the first two lines I have my array, and with setText I assign the number. but i can't get it to work ..

```
            String[] shuffledKeys = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};

        Random random = new Random(); // or create a static random field...
        String randString = shuffledKeys[random.nextInt(shuffledKeys.length)];

        key0.setText(shuffledKeys.get(0));
        key1.setText(shuffledKeys.get(0));
        key2.setText(shuffledKeys.get(0));
        key3.setText(shuffledKeys.get(0));
        key4.setText(shuffledKeys.get(0));
        key5.setText(shuffledKeys.get(0));
        key6.setText(shuffledKeys.get(0));
        key7.setText(shuffledKeys.get(9));
        key8.setText(shuffledKeys.get(8));
        key9.setText(shuffledKeys.get(9));
```

Comment: What is it that isn't working or what behavior is happening that you don't want to happen?

Comment: actually it just doesn't work, meaning in this way I assign 0,0,0,0,0,0,9,9,9

and not random..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] keys = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};

Set<String> addedKeys = new HashSet<String>();
List<String> shuffledKeys = new ArrayList<String>();

Random random = new Random();

while (shuffledKeys.size() < keys.length) {
  int index = Math.abs(random.nextInt() % keys.length);
  if (!addedKeys.contains(keys[index])) {
    addedKeys.add(keys[index]);
    shuffledKeys.add(keys[index]);
  }
}

/// Shuffled keys should now actually be "shuffled"

key0.setText(shuffledKeys.get(0));
key1.setText(shuffledKeys.get(1));
key2.setText(shuffledKeys.get(2));
key3.setText(shuffledKeys.get(3));
key4.setText(shuffledKeys.get(4));
key5.setText(shuffledKeys.get(5));
key6.setText(shuffledKeys.get(6));
key7.setText(shuffledKeys.get(7));
key8.setText(shuffledKeys.get(8));
key9.setText(shuffledKeys.get(9));
```

Comment: ok, the crash has been fixed, but my numbers are always populated the same way. all are still assigned in order

Comment: You were doing `shuffledKeys.get(0)` repeatedly in your code. If you have them increment it should solve your problem....